# Cookie doesn't set with 'secure' flag on HTTPS - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, https

I'm trying to set `document.cookie` with `secure` flag, like this:

```
document.cookie = 'token=hR_lVjFDKAUbuRRKmNCSZ3mlvpcWi1sA; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; domain=https://my-secured-fake-site.com; path=/; secure';
```

But it doesn't work at https://my-secured-fake-site.com (which equals to `domain` attribute in desirable cookie string).
Please help to understand what's wrong.

Comment: the secure come has come secured from the server that cannot be set on the client

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault. I need to set `domain` as `my-secured-fake-site.com` instead of `https://my-secured-fake-site.com` as I tried before.